# How do I upgrade Pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr, pandoc

When I click on Knit, the error message below populates

```
Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found (see the help page ?rmarkdown::pandoc_available).
Execution halted
```

I tried using:

```
Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO_PANDOC")

Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC="C:/Users/andre/anaconda4/envs/rstudio/Library/Scripts/pandoc")
```

Not sure what should happen next?  I was able to run the Knit earlier this evening.